# Check if a field value is not already used avoiding checkout in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a store where `billing_address_1` **MUST** be unique to the user, and can be different for different products, but only one user can use one specific address per `SKU/product`. During checkout, I would like to validate whether the `billing_address_1` has been used by another user and inform the user to change the `billing_address_1` provided. If the billing address supplied has been used previously by that user, it is OK. How would I go about adding this to the checkout process as a function?

I have created a sql query which can grab the basic details I need but would think using the woocommerce hooks would be better and stored as an array, checking if the address has been previously used by another user, if not proceed... Also, I think the query would be probably better (and faster) if filtered by the product in the cart (only one product can be added to the cart).

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT
  A.ID as order_id, B.meta_value as b_address_1, C.meta_value as user_id
FROM wp_posts as A
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta B
  ON A.id = B.post_id AND B.meta_key = '_billing_address_1'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta C
  ON A.id = C.post_id AND C.meta_key = '_customer_user'
WHERE A.post_type = 'shop_order'
ORDER BY order_id DESC
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Is this some sort of billing issue or do you only want one customer per address for some reason? Might be easier to figure out a better solution if you can answer this.

Comment: @Syn Correct, we want to ensure only one billing address is associated with one user, and a second user cannot checkout with the same billing address since the billing address is used for something else where unique address per user is required. So, the user can use the same billing address 1 if they have previously used it, but another user cannot use it.

Comment: in my head, I see it as this, user is about to checkout, validate whether supplied billing_address_1 has been previously used for an order. IF not, proceed with order, if yes, check user_id #, if same user id number has used address before, proceed with checkout, if another user id has purchased the product with the same address, do not proceed with checkout and prompt user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Try the following code that will check if `billing_address_1` field value is not already used by someone else, avoiding placing the order and displaying a custom error notice:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'custom_billing_address_1_validation', 50, 2 );
function custom_billing_address_1_validation( $data, $errors ) {
    if( isset( $data['billing_address_1'] ) ) :

    global $wpdb;

    $customer_id       = get_current_user_id();
    $billing_address_1 = sanitize_text_field( $data['billing_address_1'] );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value != $customer_id
        AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_billing_address_1'
        AND pm2.meta_value LIKE '$billing_address_1'
    " );

    if ( $count > 0 )
        $errors->add( 'validation', __('The "Street Address" already exist, please contact us.') );

    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> Now to enable this functionality at product level, **is much more complicated and too broad** as it is just **a real development**. Remember that customer address **is not linked to products**…

Comment: AMAZING. Is that not prone to sql injections though? - nevermind - you sanitized it

Comment: accepted. I modified it a bit since I had another separate table to check as well (banned users). Thank you!

Comment: so I have been testing it and it doesnt seem to catch the address. I dont have 'purchasing' on my shop, that is, woocommerce cart needs payment = false ... is that an issue?

Comment: In fact, I came across a different hook for checking at checkout `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` - would this be a better solution in this case?

Comment: @RickMorty For me it's working… If it doesn't work with the actual hook, it will not work better with "woocommerce_after_checkout_validation" as woocommerce_checkout_process is used for fields validation as some other hooks… I will retest that deeper and I will notify you.

Comment: Would it be wise to make the function as an Onchange - check? or would that be too demanding on the database?

Comment: I have tried the sql command on its own and it returns proper (expected) values so I cannot understand why when placed as a function it is not working...

Comment: I did retest that and it just works fine. So there is something in your theme, or a plugin or some customizations that are making trouble. So you should try to join me on skype or google Hangouts chat searching for Loïc de Marcé…